# How to deploy and interact with hyperledger fabric through the internet?

Tags: hyperledger

How can I deploy a multi-organization hyperledger fabric project on multiple hosts through the internet? Why do all hyperledger tutorials ignore this issue and deploy test projects on the local machine in contrary to expected real applications?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the tutorial is only a tutorial.
To build this into a production on the Internet, many network environmental factors must be considered.

If you want to test a blockchain network on the Internet, try building it using the cloud such as AWS, Azure, Bluemix, etc.

And.. there are many examples. 
[kctheservang/multi-host-first-network-fabric](https://kctheservant.medium.com/multi-host-deployment-for-first-network-hyperledger-fabric-v2-273b794ff3d) 
[wahabjawed/fabric-multiple-host](https://wahabjawed.medium.com/hyperledger-fabric-on-multiple-hosts-a33b08ef24f) 
[IBM/fabric-on-kubernetes](https://github.com/IBM/blockchain-network-on-kubernetes)